# How to use this LUA table?

Tags: lua

I'am new to LUA and I'am using it to create some Envoy Filters. So, I have found a piece of code with a Table like this :

```
MyClass = {
  [":path"] = "something"
}
```

I want to add a contructor to MyClass, so I do this :

```
function MyObject:new (o, path)
   o = o or {}
   setmetatable(o, self)
   self.__index = self
   self.path = path -- Here is the problem
   return o
end
```

So, my problem is : How can I access to the [":path"] variable in my contructor to assign a value?

`self.path` does not work

`self.:path` does not work

`self.[":path"]` does not work

This syntax [":foo"] is something I have found nowhere else than in my Envoy sample filter.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dot notation is a syntactic sugar for a complete form.

`table.name` is equivalent to `table["name"]`. So in your case it should be `self[":path"]`

Comment: Ok .... I'am sooo bad ^^ It's like javascript in fact. It's the only one I did not think too :)
Thank you

Comment: @FredMériot, yes, Lua is quite similar to javascript in few ways, but Lua is more general, more uniform in its concepts :)